# Problema de CORS / Laravel + React

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, axios, cors

Estoy desarrollando una app, le cual es una api en Laravel 10 y el front en Reactjs.
Ambos estan en un servidor local dentro de mi empresa. Para levantar apache utilizo Xampp y el proyecto de react utilizo el siguiente script

```
"start": "vite --port 5000"
```

A xampp lo configure en el puerto 3000.
Esto hace que cuando accedo desde una pc dentro de la red de la empresa acceda al proyecto de react mediante la ip 192.168.100.11:5000. Hasta ahi anda todo perfecto.

Luego, le pedi a la gente de sistema que me haga ip publica ese puerto, lo cual hace que la ip se exponga en una url del siguiente tipo

> nombreempresa.ddns.net:3000

Y el back se expuso de la siguiente manera

> nombreempresa.ddns.net:3001/proyecto/public/

Pero cuando intento realizar una solicitud obtengo problemas de CORS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que me estaria faltando configurar para poder acceder desde afuera de la red de la empresa